# Pass UILabel text from UITableViewCell to a different function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I've tried searching around for an answer, but have not succeeded in doing so.

I want to pass the text in one of the UILabel's the cell holds. I am not entirely sure on how to do this. I am trying to pass the content of one of the UILabels into the swipeTableViewCell didTriggerRightUtilityWithIndex function, as I am using SWTableViewCell.

The table is populated with items from a mysql table.

This is my current UITableViewCell function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    if([taskArray valueForKey:@"TaskData"] != [NSNull null])
    {
        GroupDataTableViewCell *cell = (GroupDataTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        // Add utility buttons
        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                    title:@"Les mer"];

        cell.rightUtilityButtons = rightUtilityButtons;
        cell.delegate = self;


        if (cell == nil) {

            //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableItem" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSDictionary    *item = [taskArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([item objectForKey:@"TaskID"] != [NSNull null])
           cell.numberTextField.text = [item objectForKey:@"TaskID"];
        if([item objectForKey:@"Title"] != [NSNull null])
           cell.titleTextField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Title"];
        if([item objectForKey:@"Description"] != [NSNull null])
           cell.descriptionTextField.text = [item objectForKey:@"Description"];


        if([[selfArray valueForKey:@"CheckStat"] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        else if([[selfArray valueForKey:@"CheckStat"] length] == 0)
        {
            if ([[item objectForKey:@"CheckStat"] containsString:@"1"])
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            else
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < [[[selfArray valueForKey:@"CheckStat"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] count]; i++)
            {
                NSString    *checkedNumStr = [[[selfArray valueForKey:@"CheckStat"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:i];
                //if (i >= [taskArray count] || [checkedNumStr intValue] >= [taskArray count])
                    //break;
                if ([checkedNumStr intValue] == indexPath.row + 1)
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        }


        return cell;
    }
    else
        return  nil;
}
```

I want to send the cell.descriptionField.text from there to this code, when the rightUtilityButton is activated:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        {
            // More button is pressed
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bookmark" message:@"Description" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
            break;
        }
        case 1:

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So, I want the cell.descriptionTextField.text from the first snippet into the second snippet. I am not entirely sure on how to do this, as I am not good with tablecells. I want the cell.descriptionTextField.text from the first snippet to show up in the alertView as the description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not store information in cell object rather than that use datasource to store information.
using index you can get the respective information that was stored in label

In your case you are storing description in label which can be later retrieved as follows

```
  -(void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
        {
      NSDictionary    *item = [taskArray objectAtIndex:index;
      //Do something with the item
        }
```

Comment: Don't "store" information in Cell objects.  Store it in the dataSource.

Answer (score 2):

Save your [item objectForKey:@"Description"] into an NSMutableArray previously created, if you order your cells with the same order as the nsmutablearray, you could access this value into your wanted function like this:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
switch (index) {
    case 0:
    {
        // More button is pressed
        NSString *desc = [myarray objectAtIndex:index];
        // Use your string wherever you want

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bookmark" message:@"Description" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        break;
    }
    case 1:

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, if you designed your dataSource properly you should already have an array with an object or dictionary for each row, and you can stash the info there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store those text in NSString* property within your class and then use wherever you need?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The text is different for each cell.